# Drupal - User Management - Out of Memory error

Tags: drupal

Working on a project where we have a Drupal 5 set-up. There are currently 25'000 users in the database, and all 25'000 have a role with an expiry. Now every single time the admin tries to edit the user data (eg. Update User Role), the User Management page throws "Fatal Error: Out of Memory" on submission. Refreshing the user listing shows that the update has been made.

What can this be? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out, the issue was the XML sitemap module. It was indexing every single user, turned off user indexing and memory problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can be configured to use a limited amount of memory per HTTP request by means of the [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) configuration option.

Drupal 6 works around this and other resource limitations by distributing the work across several requests (via HTTP redirect or AJAX) using the *Batch API*.

With Drupal 5, I suggest increasing the memory limit. If this still does not work, investigate where the memory goes. Try deactivating modules until your memory problem goes away. This might not give you a solution, but might at least point you to the module that causes the memory problem.

Comment: Hey Oswald! Thanks for your time. We have already upped the memory to 50MB, we have experimented with 128mb previously but that still was not enough. This timeout is occuring even on updating a single user's profile. Please help :(

Comment: Turns out, the issue was the XML sitemap module. It was indexing every single user, turned off user indexing and memory problem resolved. You answered first however, so you get the points!

Comment: @Dmitri I'm flattered, but I don't think this is how stackoverflow should work. That's why I shamelessly incorporated your solution into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to make the memory limit to 128m in php.ini file and in settings.php file in drupal

http://drupal.org/node/207036

....then try to restart the apache if its possible

good luck

Comment: Hey Maged. As mentioned above we have already raised the limit to 128MB. User operations are still slow, and don't get past the out of memory error. The edits appear, but on submission an error page is shown. I have heard that APC might improve this, have you had any experience with such? Thanks!

Comment: Turns out, the issue was the XML sitemap module. It was indexing every single user, turned off user indexing and memory problem resolved. Oswald answered first, so he gets preferred answer, but have an upvote! :)